# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ' + '. 5

Tags: sql-server, database

```
select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)" +
"from Gl_Transaction where Accountno like'1%' select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)" +
"from Gl_Transaction where Accountno like'2%'" +
"select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)" +
"from Gl_Transaction where Accountno like'3%'" +
"select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)" +
"from Gl_Transaction where Accountno like'4%'" +
"select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)" +
"from Gl_Transaction where Accountno like'5%'";
```

Comment: Should there be a '+' between `'1%'` and `select`?

Comment: same error whwn i add  '+' between '1%' and select

Comment: Clean up the missing quotation marks and see if you still get the errors please. Repost the newly updated code and error message

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can't chain queries like that.

Comment: i want to get data where account num starts with 001

Comment: What language is this written in? This does not look like an SQL Server query. Is this an SQL query embedded in another language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL doesn't use `"..."+` to concatenate lines... remove them.

And if AccountNo is an integer, you have to covert to a string to use LIKE.

```
select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
from Gl_Transaction where convert(varchar(max),Accountno) like'1%' 

select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
from Gl_Transaction where convert(varchar(max),Accountno) like'2%'

select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
from Gl_Transaction where convert(varchar(max),Accountno) like'3%'

select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
from Gl_Transaction where convert(varchar(max),Accountno) like'4%'

select SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
from Gl_Transaction where convert(varchar(max),Accountno) like'5%'
```

Comment: ok ..but if i want to get value where account num starts from 001 then which query i can made?

Comment: What value?  If you want to see everything, just do `SELECT * FROM Gl_Transaction where convert(varchar(max),Accountno) like '1%'`

Comment: but the answer is null when i make thus query

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you there, if you want AccountNum 001 you can do  `SELECT * FROM Gl_Transaction where convert(varchar(max),Accountno) like '001%'`

Comment: i have different accounts in mu table transaction... but i only want the records whose account num stars from 001

Comment: Do you want the accounts 001* ONLY, or do you want 001*, 002*, 003* and NOT 000* ??

Comment: i want 001,002 and 003

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM Gl_Transaction where convert(int,left(convert(varchar(max),Accountno),3)) between 1 and 3`

Comment: they are giving 004 record also... but i want just 001,002,003

Comment: i edited it to 1 to 3 already  `SELECT * FROM Gl_Transaction where convert(int,left(convert(varchar(max),Accountno),3)) between 1 and 3`

Comment: i have 1 more problem ... i am uploading that question kindly do answer

Answer (score 0):

If your code is supposed to be an SQL Server query, you don't need the quotation marks (`"`). Instead you can just have individual queries that look something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
FROM Gl_Transaction
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max),Accountno) LIKE'1%'

SELECT SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
FROM Gl_Transaction
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max),Accountno) LIKE'2%'

SELECT SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
FROM Gl_Transaction
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max),Accountno) LIKE'3%'

SELECT SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
FROM Gl_Transaction
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max),Accountno) LIKE'4%'

SELECT SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
FROM Gl_Transaction
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max),Accountno) LIKE'5%'
```

## EDIT:

It seems you actually just wanted a query that will return data where account number starts with 001, 002, or 003.

Here are two simple queries that will do what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
FROM Gl_Transaction
WHERE CONVERT(int,left(CONVERT(varchar(max),Accountno),3)) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

*Thanks to @JiggsJedi for proposing this alternative (which I feel is better than my initial suggestion below)*

or

```
SELECT SUM(dr_amount)-SUM(cr_amount)
FROM Gl_Transaction
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max),Accountno) LIKE'001%'
OR CONVERT(varchar(max),Accountno) LIKE'002%'
OR CONVERT(varchar(max),Accountno) LIKE'003%'
```

Comment: and if i want account num starts with 001,002 and 003
how can i concatinate them?

Comment: Do you want (1) one query that will return data with account num starting with 001 or 002 or 003? **OR** (2) several queries, where the first will return data with account num starting with 001, and the second will return data with account num starting with 002, etc.?

Comment: 1 query which gives 00,002,003 records